# How to read a text file from a web application

Tags: java, file, war

I am writing a Jersey Restful service to be deployed on Tomcat via a war file.

The service needs to read data in 3 text files. The text files need to exist on the file system or read from the classpath. I have tried to read the data from the file system and classpath but neither are working. I would be happy with either way - it doesn't matter.

If it was to use the following code,can someone tell me where to place the text file specified  so that the code picks up the file?

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myfile.txt")));
```

I am getting a null pointer exception.

If I was to read the file from the file system, use the following code, where do I place the files in my Jar?

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("myFile.txt");
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(fs);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

I am getting a FileNotFound exception.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I copied my text file into the `WEB-INF/classes` folder and used `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/myfile.txt")` and it worked.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar thread in [Java - Relative path of a file in a java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395737/java-relative-path-of-a-file-in-a-java-web-application).

If you want to know in real time the directory, you can access the class [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) methods. I believe that the method `getContextPath` might be useful to you.

Comment: I've tried that. I have been using every combination of paths and placing the file in different locations but my app cannot find the file. Can you give me an example of a path string and location?