# Relative path to store a file in any computer - Java

Tags: java, file

I have used [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395737/java-relative-path-of-a-file-in-a-java-web-application) to read a file on my project. but i need to store likewise i don't know how to do this? please help me.

for reading a file i have taken the code from the link

```
InputStream csv = 
             SomeClassInTheSamePackage.class.getResourceAsStream("filename.csv");
```

Like this can anyone help me with writing a file

currently I'm using this code:

```
 Writer output = null;
 output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./filename.csv"));
```

But it throws FileNotFound Exception at runtime

Issue is with locating file path. it works fine if i give absolute path. but it needs to be run in any computer

Comment: Have you tried writing to just `'filename.csv'` instead of to `'./filename.csv'`?

Comment: @bernie What if `someClassInTheSamePackage` is not in the current package?

Comment: SomeClassInTheSamePackage denotes any java file in the package to use as reference

Comment: @Yuzi Don't you think that letting someone to write a file in java package would be serious security issue?

Answer (score 0):

The FileWriter will create files as required. It doesn't have to exist already.

The only way you can get this error is if the current working directory no longer exists or you don't have permission to create a file in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions:

```
Writer output = null;
if (new File("./filename.csv").canWrite()) {
   System.out.println("You have not permissions");
} else {
   output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./filename.csv"));
   ...
}
```

Comment: Issue is with locating file path. it works fine if i give absolute path. but it needs to run in any computer

Answer (score 0):

OK..Use the following code to get the path of file:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path+File.separator+"filename.csv");
```

**EDIT**

Here is a Demo Code that is creating file `"pqr.txt"` in package `myPackage`. Given that I am executing the class file using command `java myPackage.AccessCheck` i.e from one directory above the mypackage.

```
package myPackage;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.File;
public class AccessCheck
{
    protected void callme()
    {

        try
        {
            String name = System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+AccessCheck.class.getPackage().getName()+File.separator+"pqr.txt";
            System.out.println(name);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(name);
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        AccessCheck asc = new AccessCheck();
        asc.callme();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get File.separator

Comment: `File.separator` gives The `system-dependent` default `name-separator` String. For example : On Microsoft Windows systems it is "\" `(c:\abc)` .. Whereas in  On UNIX systems the value of this field is "/" . Watch here for more information on this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator

Comment: Tell me the name of your `package` and the absolute path of this `file`. And also tell me that from which directory are you executing `java` command.

Comment: @VishalK `"./filename.csv"` is nothing but `"filename.csv"` that means he/she is storing file in the root folder, which is working fine for me. I mean both are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `getResourceAsStream()`, call `class.getResource()` or `classLoader.getResource()`. These functions return a URL giving the location of the resource. If the resource is a plain file on the filesystem, the URL will be a `file:` URL.

Once you have the URL, you can convert it to a `URI` and pass it to the `File` constructor which takes a URI. Then you can use the `File` object to open the file.

Note that `getResource()` can return URLs that the `File` constructor can't deal with. For example, if the resource is found in a jar file, then the URL might look like this:

```
jar:file:/C:/path/to/JDK/lib/vm.jar!/java/lang/Object.class
```

The `File` constructor can't deal with URLs like this. This may or may not be a concern for you.