# use existing sqlite database in java webapp

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, web-applications

I have a java web app.  I need to point to an existing sqlite database that I have in the project root (in eclipse).

I have all of the required drivers/jars.

The problem is that code to select from my sqlite database tables runs against a newly created database.  I get an error that my table "Table1" doesn't exist.  I believe this is because a new database is being created as opposed to using the existing sqlite database in the root with the tables and data that I need.

Does anyone know how I can force this local sqlite database to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [SQLite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html), a new database will be created by default if it doesn't find an existing one -- so the most likely explanation is that the path in your connection string isn't pointing to your pre-existing database.

See the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395737/java-relative-path-of-a-file-in-a-java-web-application) about relative paths in web apps: if your web-app is a servlet, use [ServletContext.getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to get the path to your database to use in the connection string. So, if your existing database is in /WEB-INF:

```
ServletContext.getResource("/WEB-INF/my.db");
```