# Walk backward in a file path

Tags: java

In my program I got a file path `E:\MyProject\ImageUploads\TestImageUpload\target\TestImageUpload2\`

I need to walk backward and get  `E:\MyProject\ImageUploads\TestImageUpload`

What is the best way to do in `java`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Relative path of a file in a java web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395737/java-relative-path-of-a-file-in-a-java-web-application)

Comment: No, I didn't get a solution from it

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197049/how-to-get-just-the-parent-directory-name-of-a-specific-file

Comment: possibly split the file path string by `\\` remove the last two elements

Comment: Yes, It will work, I think there is a better way to do it in java

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean this?

```
for(File file = new File("E:\\MyProject\\ImageUploads\\TestImageUpload\\target\\TestImageUpload2\\"); file != null; file = file.getParentFile())
    System.out.println(file);
```

Output:

```
E:\MyProject\ImageUploads\TestImageUpload\target\TestImageUpload2
E:\MyProject\ImageUploads\TestImageUpload\target
E:\MyProject\ImageUploads\TestImageUpload
E:\MyProject\ImageUploads
E:\MyProject
E:\
```

Comment: at times .getparentfile will result in null (e.g. relative path)... so uhm don't think that will do the trick...

Comment: @witchedwiz what "backward" means is unclear in OP. `new File("..\\..").getParentFile()` is clearly `new File("..")`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your image is
C:/MyProject/ImageUploads/TestImageUpload/target/TestImageUpload2/someimg.png

apache common utils is your best friend..

```
enter code here

               FilenameUtils.getFullPathNoEndSeparator(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

The result is => C:/MyProject/ImageUploads/TestImageUpload/target/TestImageUpload2

then usual drill..
hope it clarifies..

the .getparent()  applied on a file created with a likewise parent, otherwise it's a no-no, thus i'd prefer going with filenameutils and that's about that..

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use this:

```
new File("E:\\MyProject\\ImageUploads\\TestImageUpload\\target\\TestImageUpload2\\")
    .getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile()
```

The basic idea is that `getAbsoluteFile()` will convert the path into an absolute path, and then `getParentFile()` will find the parent of the named file. You can apply `getParentFile()` repeatedly (until it returns null) if you want to go through ALL of the parents.

This also works regardless of whether or not the path ends with a slash.

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for my requirement.

```
int i = 2;
File filePath;
for(filePath = new File(path); i > 0; filePath = filePath.getParentFile())
    i--;
```