# getting java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:

Tags: java, file-io

I have a file named upgradePagePromoCodeState.json under /common.

When I use a file path like this:

```
/work/xxx/app/src/main/webapp.war/common/upgradePagePromoCodeState.json
```

it's executed in local but not in stages.
How can I give a path to work in stage an well as in local?

```
String filePath = "/work/xxx/app/src/main/webapp.war/common/upgradePagePromoCodeState.json";
try {
    String jsonText = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while pasing a file", e);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "in stages" ?

Comment: are you trying to get a file inside `war` file ?

Comment: @benjaminc yes. I want to read a file from war file

Comment: @Stultuske stages mean testing environments(UAT).

Comment: have a look at this question and answers please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395737/java-relative-path-of-a-file-in-a-java-web-application

Comment: @KiranKumar what does 'stages' mean ?

Comment: @benjaminc stages mean testing environments(UAT)